# Website content was copied resulting in decreased traffic

Tags: seo, hacking, botattack

My website with automobile niche has been struggling to stand again plagiarism and bot-attacks from last few months.In last quarter, 3 different domains were setup with exact replica of all the contents were made resulting in decreased traffic.

We are sure that they've put some kind of bot to copy all the pages as We've more than 50,000 articles copied. We have lost 30% organic traffic in last quarter.

The attack goes like this -

1. A new domain is set up and all the pages are copied with meta tags,
   description, content, Adsense ad slots etc.
   The website starts appearing in google for similar keywords and we start losing the traffic.
2. The spammy website doesn't show the copied content, but redirects
   users to some other websites.
3. As soon as We report it togoogle and it starts disappearing, a new
   domain is set up with same method.

We've tried to contact google via product forum and they've helped us once  by flagging the site and removing it from searches. What can be done to make sure that such attacks doesn't affect us in future?

Comment: this is not a question.

Comment: @JosipIvic I've updated the question. Is it still not a fit for this platform?

Comment: If you have a Google Search Console (webmaster tools) account, you may be able to use this page: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/spamreport?hl=en

Comment: Also, if you have a dedicated IP address, check how the bad domain resolves; it could be pointing to your IP address. This has happened before. If that is the case, then you should be able to use .htaccess to redirect to your site so that it is properly served and Google will index your site and not theirs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step is to report the spam to Google, additionally you can do a whois search on the domains and report the spam to the registrar, most registrars have anti spam policies.